# Streaming Data over USB with Android Smartphone

Tags: android, usb, smartphone

Is it possible to use the Android NDK to treat a smartphone USB port as a serial device?

For a use case where you would want to process a continuous data stream from a 3rd party device connected via a USB cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> continuous data stream from a 3rd party device connected via a USB cable

From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html): USB host mode is supported in Android 3.1 and higher.

You need this when your 3d party device is a usb "device" - intended to be plugged into a PC. Not all Smartphones can act as USB Host, though.